# UIPageViewControllerDelegate method is not invoked in super class

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I implement `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` method in my super class `WDDesignPhotoBookViewController`. (It is derived from another super class)

Afterwards I create a sub class called `WDPreviewBookViewController`. But when I try to drag and turn to next page, I encounter a crash.
In order to fix it, I had to implement UIPageViewControllerDelegate method in my subclass and call some protected method in super class. Actually both implementations in super and sub class are just the same. One of the method which I implemented is as following:

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed {
```

I think the solution is not elegant.
Do you also met such problem? Any suggestion? Will forward message be helpful in this case? I may try some thoughts later.

I show the call stack when crashing:
[image: The beginning of the call stack]

[image: The End of the call stack]

Comment: Can you clarify why crash was happened?

Comment: @kirander I upload the call stack screenshots when crashing. I think it maybe can explain the crash.

Comment: Looks like cycle, where "tlsw_pageVIewController:didFinishAnimating:.." method calling himself. You should find that place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing delegates method in subclass again in that case to execute super class's delegate method implementation you have to call super class method manually like this

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed{

[super pageViewController:pageViewController didFinishAnimating:finished previousViewControllers:previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:completed];

}
```

Comment: Actually the system will look for method in superclasses automatically. Your realisation needed only if you need to do additional job in subclass.

Comment: Yes you are right, but if you are implementing that method agin in subclass in that case it ignore implementation in superclass.

Comment: Yes, it can be a solution, but the problem is not there, I suppose.

Comment: @kirander Yes, you are right. I consider the problem is not there. The problem is that why "I had to implement three delegate methods in the sub class and it seems that system does not look for method in superclasses automatically".